# Show staged changes in Sublime Merge

Tags: git, sublimemerge

I don't see any way to view my staged changes in Sublime Merge. I can only see changes not staged for commit.

Is there a way to view staged changes? I'm looking for something similar to using `git diff --cached` but in Sublime Merge's UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The demo on the the [Sublime Merge website](https://www.sublimemerge.com/) shows this, although not very clearly.

If you scroll to the bottom of the 'Working Directory' section (list of changes), theres a 'Staged Files' section. From there you can see all the staged changes and unstage them.

[image: A screenshot of Sublime Merge with an arrow pointing to the 'Staged Files' section]